# Show that 1 + $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $I + A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then 1+$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $I+A$.

What is the corresponding eigenvector?

What I have done so far (if it is correct at all...):

$(I+A)x=Ix+Ax=1x+Ax=1x+{\lambda}x=(1+\lambda)x$, thus, $1+{\lambda}$ is an eigenvector of $I+A$

But how do I find the corresponding eigenvector just from the information above?

Comment: The eigenvector is $x$. Do you know the definition of "eigenvector"?

Comment: @T.Bongers: Simple as that :D. I was thinking in a more complicated manner, like solving the system $(I+A)-(1+\lambda)=0$ to get a vector specific for the eigenvalue $1+\lambda$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then your computation of

$$(A + I)x = (\lambda + 1) x$$

is exactly the definition that states $x$ is an eigenvector of $A + I$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda + 1$.